# Matlab - changing color of pushbuttons before pushing them

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to change the colors of some pushbuttons in mat alb before actually pushing them, but just according to the values in a certain matrix (these values may change). The following code runs but the result is odd. What I am doing wrong with the for loop?

This is an example of matrix:

```
A = [0 0 3 1 1];
```

Here I set the screen:

```
scr = get(0, 'screensize');
f1 = figure(1);
set(f1, 'menubar', 'none');
set(f1, 'position', [scr(1) scr(2) scr(3) scr(4)]);
```

These are the pushbuttons:

```
h1 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
'BackgroundColor', '[0.91 0.91 0.91]',...
'Position', [200 200 100 100]);
h2 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
'BackgroundColor', '[0.91 0.91 0.91]',...
'Position', [300 200 100 100]);
h3 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
'BackgroundColor', '[0.91 0.91 0.91]',...
'Position', [400 200 100 100]);
h4 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
'BackgroundColor', '[0.91 0.91 0.91]',...
'Position', [500 200 100 100]);
h5 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
'BackgroundColor', '[0.91 0.91 0.91]',...
'Position', [600 200 100 100]);
```

I put them together in an array:

```
L = [h1 h2 h3 h4 h5];
```

Now I want the pushbuttons to change color according to the values in the matrix. So if the *first* value in the matrix is zero, the color of the *first* pushbutton should be white. If the *second* value in the matrix is zero, the color of the *second* pushbutton should be white, and so on.

```
for i = length(A)

if A(i) == 0
    set(L(i),'Backgroundcolor', 'w');
elseif A(i) == 1
    set(L(i),'Backgroundcolor','b');
elseif A(i) == 2
    set(L(i),'Backgroundcolor','y');
elseif A(i) == 3
    set(L(i),'Backgroundcolor','g');

end
end
```

But in the end I just get the last pushbutton blue, and the others unchanged! They should all be changing color.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please edit your question to say what exactly your code does and what you expect. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop only goes over the last index. Change it to

```
for i = 1 : length(A)
```

and it will iterate correctly.

Comment: What if I want to iterate through a 5 by 2 matrix as `A = [0 0 3 1 1, 0 0 1 1 0]` instead of a 5 by 1 matrix, having two rows of pushbuttons? In that case I have a problem because the length of A is always 5.

Comment: do a nested for-loop, `m=1:size(A,1)` and `n=1:size(A,2)`